# How to enable touchpad scrolling and tapping in Debian Wheezy KDE?

Tags: debian, kde, touchpad, synaptic

I'm trying to turn on scrolling and tapping with my laptop's touch-pad (the 2 left and right buttons are ok). I'm on Debian 7.3 (Wheezy) KDE-desktop and I have a Synaptic touch-pad. My laptop is an old HP model of 2007 therefore it doesn't support multi-touching. As *root* I created a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf` file which I have copied below. Then in Konsole I gave `synclient -l` and got back the following code:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1752
RightEdge               = 5192
TopEdge                 = 1620
BottomEdge              = 4236
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 221
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 100
HorizScrollDelta        = 100
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0398
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 401
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 1
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 1
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.100007
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 25
VertHysteresis          = 25
ClickPad                = 0
```

This is the content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Touchpad"
MatchIsTouchpad "yes"
Driver "synaptics"
Option "MinSpeed" "0.4"
Option "MaxSpeed" "0.9"
Option "AccelFactor" "0"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "3"
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "0"
Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "0"
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
Option "CoastingSpeed" "8"
Option "CornerCoasting" "1"
Option "TouchpadOff " "0"
EndSection
```

I've installed `apt-get install server-xorg-input-synaptics` and rebooted the system after the creation of the `synaptics.conf` file but nothing has changed.

What should I do to get it working?

Comment: I tried what **terdon** said and it initially worked but after restarting the system all the changes had disappeared. I then tried _synapticks_ from the **K start menu > Applications > Utilities** (I had installed it previously, but couldn't see it in the system tray). I read carefully each instruction and configured it properly this time. Then I restarted the system and the tapping and scrolling were still working!

Comment: Kali Linux 2.0 with i3 Desktop.
Also for me "synclient TapButton1=1" solved issue.

Comment: To have hardware details here would be helpful, etc about the manufacturer of your touchpad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `synaptiks`? It's a simple GUI program that always solved any problems with my touchpad configuration.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-config-touchpad
```

Then you should be able to run it with

```
synaptiks && synaptiks
```

(the first `synaptiks` only puts the icon in the system tray and doesn't launch the GUI for some reason)

Comment: Does this work also for Gnome?

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: I just got tapping working on my Debian AlpsPS/2 touichpad with `synclient`:

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

---

I am not an expert on this but found an old `synaptics.conf` file that I was using on a different laptop:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option          "HorizEdgeScroll"    "1"
    Option          "MaxTapTime"        "300"
    Driver          "synaptics"
EndSection
```

So, try adding `catchall` to the Identifier and changing `MatchIsTouchpad` to `on` from `yes`. Not sure if that will help but should be worth a try.

Another thing you can try is installing `tpconfig`:

```
sudo apt-get install tpconfig
```

That should give you a GUI to enable taps with:

```
 sudo tpconfig --tapmode=1
```

<sub>Though I just tried this on my system and it does not seem to work</sub>

Comment: @WobbyWindows should be `synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1`.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question I posted earlier: `synclient TapButton1=1` and `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1` did the job! You saved my day. Many many thanks.

Comment: @WobbyWindows yes, sorry, I meant `VertEdgeScroll=1`.

Comment: Simply [add](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Frequently_used_options) `Option "TapButton1" "1"` to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or [other](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Override_options_in_.2Fetc.2FX11.2Fxorg.conf.d.2Fsynaptics.conf) file from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` to make your changes permanent. My tests showed that to enable tapping on the touchpad, you should provide *at least* the following: `Option "TapButton1" "1"`, `Identifier "Touchpad"`, `MatchIsTouchpad "yes"` and `Driver "synaptics"` in `Section "InputClass" (...) EndSection`.

Comment: @patryk.beza you might want to post an actual answer. That's the third version of that comment I've gotten a notification for :P

Comment: Where is the config file? Should you use `synaptics.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

In KDE there is a new program that has superceded synaptiks: `kcm-touchpad`

This program will enable a new option in the System Settings. To access this options open System Settings (systemsettings in console), and go to Input Devices -> Touchpad